# Как сделать help java?

Tags: java, chm

Пишу для курсовой программку на java с UI. Встал вопрос о прикручивании help (инструкции, о программе и т.п.). Как это делают вообще? Варианты типа html или .chm вижу, но непонятно как это делают обычно, по канонам. Ну и мануал может у кого есть, гугление ничего не дало.

Comment: Microsoft HTML Help Workshop - микрософтовская софтина для создания CHM

Comment: это сделала, но как его прикрутить к проге?

Comment: Что вы сделали? У вас уже есть готовый CHM файл под вашу программу и вам нужно его показывать при нажатии на Help?

Comment: да. CHM есть. его открытие нужно назначить на кнопку в приложении, как это сделать? как с обычным файлом?

Comment: Ну да, можно попросить ОС открыть его в соответствующем приложении, как это делается с другими зарегистрированными типами файлов

Comment: ок, спасибо. Буду пробовать. Почему-то думала, что есть отдельный алгоритм именно для добавления справок)

Answer (score 3):

Раз уж вопрос относится к Java, рекомендовал бы отказаться от типично майкрософтовских технологий, т.к. они, в отличии от Java, работают только в Windows. Я имею ввиду CHM файлы. Существует старая стандартная технология JavaHelp - по-моему ранее была частью JDK (или JEE), но Oracle её забросила. Можно найти на [GitHub](https://github.com/javaee/javahelp). Например в NetBeans help постоен именно в этой системе. Oracle имеет собственную систему - [Oracle Help Technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-083946.html). Так же имеется система на базе [Eclipse](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-echelp/index.html).

**Дополнение:** В качестве альтернативы можно сделать банальный статический web-сайт и запускать его локально через какой-нибудь Jetty. Eclipse Help примерно так и сделан.

Comment: у меня Идея, туда JavaHelp не прикрутишь(

Comment: При чём тут Идея? Вы свою курсовую программу в Идеи показывать будете? А когда на программиста выучитесь заказчикам свои программы вместе с Идеей отдавать будете? Как заказчику объяснять будете почему ваш CHM help в Linux или на MacOS не работает?

Comment: ну курсач то точно на винде) чтобы добавть help его нужно каким-то образом интегрировать в приложение, а с Явахэлпом и идеей я больше проковыряюсь чем сделаю. Можно и html, если уж кратковременность брать.

Comment: Все предложенные мной варианты в основе документации используют HTML файлы. Просто они позволяю именно интегрировать их в приложение, вызывать контекстную справку, организовывают поиск и индексацию документации, предоставляют GUI для отображения документации. Реализовать это же самое самому дольше будет.

Comment: `Oracle Help Technologies` -- это, по-моему, тот же самый `JavaHelp`, только с исправленными багами и за деньги :)

Comment: @m.vokhm скажем так - более продвинутая версия. И хотя сама она всё же бесплатная, как мне кажется, но крепко прибита гвоздиками к ADF, который уже стоит денег. Поэтому, я считаю, выбор следует делать из имеющегося у вас GUI, SWT - использовать систему от Eclipse, SWING - JavaHelp. Ну, а если судьба свела вас с оракловым ADF, то сами понимаете... Все три системы так же позволяют сделать отображение справки через web.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov не, не бесплатная. Для себя можно использовать бесплатно, а когда захотим передать продукт пользователю (неважно, продать или подарить), надо будет купить лицензию. Там в лицензии об этом четко сказно. Я вопрос изучал, мне требовалась безукоризненная лицензионна чистота. Заказчик не готов был платить еще и за их лицензию, а из своего тощего кармана мне тоже не захотелось, поэтому я от нее отказался.

Comment: @m.vokhm [OHJ and OHW are available for free from this Web site. You may redistribute OHJ as the help system for your application at no cost, and you may also implement OHW at no cost](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-083946.html) Из этого я только не понял нужно ли разработчику покупать какую-либо лицензию.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, ну что вы меня в споры втягиваете. На странице загрузки написано: *..are provided for customers under the OTN Developer License Agreement.* **OTN** (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) гласит: *... only for the purpose of developing, testing, prototyping, and demonstrating Your application and only as long as Your application has not been used for any data processing ... and not for any other purpose....  Further, You may not: ... distribute, give, or transfer ... to any third party ... *. За деньги - можно, это отдельная платная лицензия.

Comment: @m.vokhm Это,да. До загрузки я не дошел. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно справочную информацию написать на `html`, и далее уже из `UI` открывать ее при помощи `WebView`

Например, в `JavaFX` это будет выглядеть так:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
URL url = getClass().getResource("help.html");
webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 1):

Я в свое время потратил какое-то время на решение этой задачи, см. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32162/help-system-for-a-desktop-java-application.
Вариант с `CHM` не рассматривался изначально, поскольку по ТЗ программа должна был работать на всех основных платформах (Windows, Linux и Mac). Вариант с открытием браузера мы с заказчиком сочли несерьезным, там нормальный поиск сделать невозможно, и вообще несолидно как-то.

Оставшихся варианов, как я и предполагал, немного:

- Эклипсовский хелп;
- Оракловский "Help for Java";
- Старый бесплатный JavaHelp.

Первый вариант (эклипсовский) -- тяжел и по весу, и в использовании (он должен таскать за собой пол-эклипса, минимальная сборка получается в районе 100 МБ) и содержит много излишеств.

Оракловский хелп -- платный, тоже отпадает.

Остается `JavaHelp`. Это тоже не блеск -- он содержит ошибки, он выглядит страшно, индекс у него никуда не годный и наполнять надо руками, в нем не предусмотрено изменение шрифта, и он сделан на допотопном `AWT`. Для меня последнее обстоятельство было очень неприятно, моя прорамма была на `SWT`, и надо было обмениваться событиями -- программа должна открывать окна справки, при измении шрифта надо использовать FontDialog из SWT, а при изменении размеров окна справки или шрифта программа должна запомнить последнее состояние, чтобы восстановить его при следующем запуске.

Пришлось повозиться и с допиливанием самого `JavaHelp` (добавить возможность выбора шрифта), и с прокси-методами для обмена событиями между моим SWT-потоком и AWT-потоком, в котором работает JavaHelp.

Но в конце концов получилось более-менее сносно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А недавно я обнаружил, что замечательный графический редактор yEd, написанный на Java, тоже использует слегка подправленный JavaHelp, что меня утвердило во мнении, что это единственный на сегодня вариант, который дает более-менее приличные результаты и при этом не отбирает слишком много ресурсов (включая размер дистрибутива и время разработчика).

Comment: А, для курсовой... Я не заметил. Для курсовой это, пожалуй, слишком сложно.